# JQueryUI accordion won't resize if using the float CSS property

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create an accordion with JQuery UI.
I've used a layout in which the accordion floats to the left while another sidebar floats to the right. (See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MEJYu/)

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

#accordion {
    float:left;
}

#sidebar { 
    float:right;
}
```

When I use either float or the display:table/table-cell configuration the accordion doesn't resize properly to accomodate the parent div. (I'm using heightStyle:fill).

When I cancel the float property the accordion is displayed as expected.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to  set the property autoHeight. Set it true.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({autoHeight: true})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MEJYu/3/